# Roots of polynomial $a z \overline{z} + \overline{b}z + b \overline{z}+c$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am working on finding the roots of $a z \overline{z} + \overline{b}z + b \overline{z}+c$ given $a,c \in \mathbb R$ and $b \in \mathbb C$ with $|b|^2 - ac > 0$.

First, I distinguished two cases: $a=0$ and $a \neq 0$. I consider the case $a = 0$ first. In this case, the equation becomes $ \overline{b}z + b \overline{z}+c = 0$. Again, I distinguised cases: either $c=0$ or not.

Now I am working on the case $a=c=0$. The equation becomes

$$ \overline{b}z + b \overline{z} = 0$$

This is satisfied if and only if $\overline{b}z$ is purely imaginary. I distinguished 3 cases:

(i) if $b \in \mathbb R$ ($\neq 0$) then this is true for all $z \in i \mathbb R$.

(ii) if $b \in i \mathbb R$ then this is satisfied for all $z \in \mathbb R$.

(iii) if $b = u + iv$ and we write $z = x + iy$ then this is true if and only if $ux = -vy$.

> But this is where I get stuck: How to describe the set of $z \in
>  \mathbb C$ such that $(\mathrm{Re}(b))(\mathrm{Re}(z)) = -
>  (\mathrm{Im}(b))(\mathrm{Im}(z))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: If you decompose $z, b$ into real and imaginary parts as $z = x + iy$ and $b = u + iv$, then the equation becomes
$$a x^2 + a y^2 + 2 (ux + vy) + c.$$

In the special case that $a = c = 0$, the polynomial reduces to $\bar{b} z + b \bar{z}$ (or in the above notation, $2 (px - qy)$), which is $2 \Re (\bar{b} z)$, but $\Re (\bar{b} z)$ is just $b \cdot z$, where $\cdot$ is the usual Euclidean dot product on $\mathbb{C} \cong \mathbb{R}^2$. So, $z$ is a root iff it is orthogonal to $b$ (as vectors in this space).

Since $|b|^2 - 4 ac = |b|^2 > 0$, we have $b \neq 0$, and so the set of roots is a line through the origin. In particular, since $b \cdot i b = 0$, this line is spanned by $ib$, and so the the set of roots can be written as
$$\{\lambda i b : \lambda \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$

Comment: My question is specifically about the case (in your notation) $a=c=0$. Concretely, my question, as posted above asks: ''How do I describe $z$ with $px - qy=0$?''

Comment: (the question is contained in the highlighted part above)

Comment: In the special case $a = c = 0$, the polynomial reduces to $\bar{b} z + b \bar{z}$, which is $2\Re(\bar{b} z)$. But $\Re(\bar{b} z)$ is $b \cdot z$, where $\cdot$ is the usual Euclidean dot product, so a complex number $z$ is a root of the polynomial iff it is orthogonal to the given complex number $b$.

Comment: We can also describe this set more algebraically: Since $b \neq 0$ by the inequality, the such of roots is a (real) line. Since $ib \neq 0$ and $b \cdot ib = 0$, the set of roots is exactly the (real) line through the origin containing $ib$, that is, it consists of the values $\lambda ib$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the comment. I am so grateful. If you could, would you mind replacing your current answer with the text in the comment starting with ''In the special case...''? Because this comment is a spot on answer to my question. (Also, if you did do that, and if you don't mind, (I know it's not currently in my question but... if you could confirm whether doing a case distinction is even the right approach to this problem would help me greatly...)

Comment: I believe your second comment is a confirmation of my cases (i) and (ii)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful. I rewrote my answer as requested, too. The second comment also confirms your cases (1) and (2), but also (3) (note the corrected sign in the rewritten solution).